# Devise does not use custom CSS when opened directly, but works when using button on other page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, devise, haml

I have a Rails application with ActiveAdmin and an additional devise model named "Users" that I generated to keep admin and user login separated.
On the main page there are buttons for login and registration that look like this:

```
    - if !user_signed_in?
  .nav.navbar-form.navbar-right
    %a.form-control.btn.btn-register{href: 'register'} Register

  .nav.navbar-form.navbar-right.dropdown
    %button#loginMenu.btn.btn-login.dropdown-toggle{"aria-expanded" => "true", "aria-haspopup" => "true", "data-toggle" => "dropdown", :type => "button"} Login
    %div.dropdown-menu.feeds_dropdown{"aria-labelledby" => "feedMenu"}
      = render 'users/shared/new'
```

I generated the views to customize the registration menu and style it using CSS/SASS. Now when I open the registration using the button on my main page it brings me to http://localhost/register and I can see that all CSS is applied. But as soon as I reload the page or open the url directly in a new tab no styles are applied and I just see a plain and ugly HTML page.

When checking in my browsers inspector I noticed that when I reach the site using the button the request shows up marked as "xhr", if I manually load it it shows up as "document".

What is going on here and how can I make it always use the CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Welp, I feel a bit stupid now.

```
= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
```

was missing from the registration page. What made it so confusing was that it worked fine using the button on the other page. I don't understand why that happened (some optimization shenanigans I guess) but the problem is resolved now :)

Edit: It was caused by turbolinks